# Changing language of dummy document in blindtext package in Linux

Tags: linux, latex

So actually I am trying to create a dummy document using the `blindtext` package in Latex.
so whenever I am trying to create a dummy document it creates a one in German language something like: *lorem ipsum...*

So is it possible to create a dummy document in a different language like English or something else??

This is what I have tried:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible! And your code almost did it.

The CTAN page of the package you used, [ctan.org/pkg/blindtext](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext), states:

> The package supports three languages, english, (n)german and latin ...

To implement english or american or german:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Just add

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
```

or

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

in your preamble as above and as in the [package documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext/blindtext.pdf).